# Loading contour plugin of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, contour

I have installed the contour plugin on my kubuntu 13 laptop, but when I am opening qgis (2.0.1) I get the following message:

> ```
> Couldn't load plugin contour due an error when calling its classFactory() method
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 204, in startPlugin
>     plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>   File "/home/maria/.qgis2/python/plugins/contour/__init__.py", line 47, in classFactory
>     from contour import Contour
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
>     mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>   File "/home/maria/.qgis2/python/plugins/contour/contour.py", line 41, in 
>     from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString, MultiPolygon
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
>     mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
> ImportError: No module named shapely.geometry
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your install seems to be missing the shapely python module (I often get a similar error message when I install QGIS on a new machine and fire up contour for the first time).

I'm a Win user myself (so I just installed it via the OSGeo4W installer), but I imagine you should be able to find shapely via your accessible repositories.